# Display image from xml - url is too long

Tags: javascript, php, xml

I have an image stored on a database- data type longblob, and want to diplay it on the page.
I am accessing the database with php and then creating an xml file for JavaScript to handle. 
I've kinda got it working but am getting an error saying the url for the image is too long.

Here is my code-
php

```
$sql = "SELECT image1 FROM $dbtable";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><Photos>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$img = '"data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image1'] ).'" 
height="100" width="100"';
   echo "<photo>";
   echo "<image>$img</image>";
   echo "</photo>";
}
echo "</Photos>";

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

javascript

```
function getBookResponse() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            var response = xhr.responseXML;

            var theBooksDiv = document.getElementById("theBooksDiv");
            theBooksDiv.innerHTML = "";

            for (var i = 0; i < response.getElementsByTagName('photo').length; i++) {

                var bookDiv = document.createElement("div");
                bookDiv.classList.add("aBookDiv");

                var imageValueString = response.getElementsByTagName('image')[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
                var imageValueTag = createTagFromData("img");
                imageValueTag.classList.add("bookImage");
                imageValueTag.src = imageValueString;

                theBooksDiv.appendChild(bookDiv);
                bookDiv.appendChild(imageValueTag);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[this is what is displayed in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdTIg.png)

I have a feeling it is to do with the base64 encode so is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since realised it's easier to upload the images into the sites 'images' folder and to display them from there rather than place them into a database.

I found a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ipa9xAs_nTg&t=616s) that may help others having this problem.